# Path in a Tree with Indexed Leaves

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am trying to figure out how to generate the path in a tree where nodes are labeled as `(position relative to parent,height)` and leaves are indexed starting from 0. Right now I traverse the entire tree which is probably a silly way of doing it. For example the path of leaf `2` in the tree below would be: `root/(1,1)/(0,0)`

```
            root
           /   \
        (0,1) (1,1)
         / \   /  \
        0   1  2   3
```

I know how to get the last item in the path: (leaf index % branching rate, 0). But now I'm stuck on how to get the rest of the path. There's has to be a way to do it that isn't traversing the entire tree?

Comment: is anything else known about the tree, like whether it is *complete*? The example you have given is a *perfect* tree (and so also *complete*). And in your *"I know how to get"* formula, you seem to assume that the tree is at least *complete*. Is this a given?

Comment: Yup, I should have mentioned its a perfect tree. Your answer is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tree is a [perfect m-ary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-ary_tree#Types_of_m-ary_trees), then you can reuse the formula that you already found for the leaves.

Of the tree we need to know:

- *m*: the branching factor, i.e. the number of children that all internal nodes have.
- *h*: the height of the tree, i.e. the height of the root node.

Let *k* be the zero-based index of the leaf to find the path of. Then the path is:

```
[
    root,
    ((k / m^(h-1)) % m, h-1),
    ((k / m^(h-2)) % m, h-2),
    ...
    ((k / m^2    ) % m, 2  ),
    ((k / m      ) % m, 1  ),
    (k             % m, 0  )
]
```

... where division (`/`) is integer-division, and the caret (`^`) is exponentiation.

So in pseudocode, you would do (again with integer division and exponentiation):

```
get_path(m, h, k):
    path = ["root"]
    denom = m^h
    while h > 0:
        h = h - 1
        denom = denom / h
        path.append( ((k / denom) % m, h) )
    return path
```

It is maybe a bit easier in reverse:

```
get_path(m, h, k):
    path = []
    for height = 0 to h-1:
        path.append( (k % m, height) )
        k = k / m
    path.append("root")
    return reversed(path)
```